# Web link to local dropbox file

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

Is there a way to create a link (i.e  that dropbox will redirect to a local file on my computer if the file is synced?

I run my own web server and each web page maps to a folder.  i'd like to be able to create a link on that page that opens up that folder in explorer or finder?

thanks

Comment: I think if you approach this problem in different way then you might be able to solve it. First, are you caching your remote files on your local file system? If yes, then why don't you change settings in your webserver to read from you local file path.

`Example: www.dropbox.com/public/File1.jpeg
same file on your machine: /users/me/documents/dropbox/public/File1.jpeg`

Comment: The files are only stored on my local desktop.  they are not stored on the web server.

Comment: As you have mentioned "I run my own web server and each web page maps to a folder." so I am assuming you are running some sort of webserver locally on your machine (aka desktop). So manipulating your local webserver to point to a particular folder (Dropbox local folder) on your local machine (aka desktop) should be trivial, if that's the route you want to take.

Comment: No.  The web server is up in the cloud(AWS) so that multiple people can connect to it.